# Проблема с якорем

Tags: html

При переходе по якорной ссылке к якорю в меню "iPhone" отрезаются все блоки сверху.
Кто сталкивался с данной проблемой и как можно решить?
Cсылка на сайт, если понадобится : http://vcland.wg3036.wg01.ru 
Спасибо за ответы!

```css
.sp-megamenu-parent {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 250;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
.sp-megamenu-parent >li {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
.sp-megamenu-parent >li >a, .sp-megamenu-parent >li >span {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0px;
    block: ;
    padding: 0 15px;
    line-height: 46px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: Oswald;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #f8f6f7;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sp-menu" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="position: static;"><div class="sp-column ">   <div class="sp-megamenu-wrapper">
    <a id="offcanvas-toggler" class="visible-sm visible-xs" aria-label="Menu" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" title="Menu"></i></a>
    <ul class="sp-megamenu-parent menu-slide-down hidden-sm hidden-xs"><li class="sp-menu-item current-item active"><a class=" hohohome" href="/index.php">Главная</a></li><li class="sp-menu-item"><a class=" iphone" href="#iphone777">iPhone</a></li><li class="sp-menu-item"><a class=" xiaomi" href="/index.php/xiaomi">Xiaomi</a></li><li class="sp-menu-item"><a class=" huawei" href="/index.php/huawei">Huawei</a></li><li class="sp-menu-item"><a class="contacts" href="/index.php/kontakty">Контакты</a></li></ul>   </div>
  </div></div>
    <section id="section-id-1510554358" class="sppb-section "><div id="skrew-section-id-1510554358"></div><div id="skrew2-section-id-1510554358"></div><div class="sppb-row-container"><div class="sppb-section-title sppb-text-center"><h2 class="sppb-title-heading"></h2><h2 style="font-family: Oswald;">МЫ РАБОТАЕМ С МОДЕЛЯМИ:</h2></div><div class="sppb-row"><div class="sppb-col-md-12" id="column-wrap-id-1510554359"><div id="column-id-1510554359" class="sppb-column  sppb-wow fadeInDown sppb-animated" data-sppb-wow-duration="300ms" data-sppb-wow-delay="100ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 300ms; animation-delay: 100ms; animation-name: fadeInDown;"><div class="sppb-column-addons"><div id="sppb-addon-1560777907650" class="clearfix"><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html "><div class="sppb-addon-content"><p id="iphone777"></p></div></div></div><div id="sppb-addon-1560716582083" class="clearfix"><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-header sppb-text-center"><h2 class="sppb-addon-title">iPhone</h2></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sppb-col-md-3" id="column-wrap-id-1560711743759"><div id="column-id-1560711743759" class="sppb-column"><div class="sppb-column-addons"><div id="sppb-addon-1560716330457" class=" sppb-wow fadeInUp clearfix sppb-animated" data-sppb-wow-duration="800ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 800ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;"><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-single-image sppb-text-center  iphone-item"><h3 class="sppb-addon-title">iPhone X</h3><div class="sppb-addon-content"><div class="sppb-addon-single-image-container"><img class="sppb-img-responsive" src="/images/2019/06/16/iphone-x.png" alt="Image" title="iPhone X"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sppb-col-md-3" id="column-wrap-id-1560711743760"><div id="column-id-1560711743760" class="sppb-column"><div class="sppb-column-addons"><div id="sppb-addon-1560716330462" class=" sppb-wow fadeInUp clearfix sppb-animated" data-sppb-wow-duration="800ms" data-sppb-wow-delay="300ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 800ms; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;"><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-single-image sppb-text-center  iphone-item"><h3 class="sppb-addon-title">iPhone XS</h3><div class="sppb-addon-content"><div class="sppb-addon-single-image-container"><img class="sppb-img-responsive" src="/images/2019/06/17/ipone-xs1.png" alt="Image" title="iPhone XS"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sppb-col-md-3" id="column-wrap-id-1560711743761"><div id="column-id-1560711743761" class="sppb-column"><div class="sppb-column-addons"><div id="sppb-addon-1560716330467" class=" sppb-wow fadeInUp clearfix sppb-animated" data-sppb-wow-duration="800ms" data-sppb-wow-delay="600ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 800ms; animation-delay: 600ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;"><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-single-image sppb-text-center  iphone-item"><h3 class="sppb-addon-title">iPhone 8</h3><div class="sppb-addon-content"><div class="sppb-addon-single-image-container"><img class="sppb-img-responsive" src="/images/2019/06/17/ipone-8.png" alt="Image" title="iPhone 8"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sppb-col-md-3" id="column-wrap-id-1560711743762"><div id="column-id-1560711743762" class="sppb-column"><div class="sppb-column-addons"><div id="sppb-addon-1560716808369" class=" sppb-wow fadeInUp clearfix sppb-animated" data-sppb-wow-duration="800ms" data-sppb-wow-delay="900ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 800ms; animation-delay: 900ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;"><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-single-image sppb-text-center  iphone-item"><h3 class="sppb-addon-title">iPhone 7</h3><div class="sppb-addon-content"><div class="sppb-addon-single-image-container"><img class="sppb-img-responsive" src="/images/2019/06/17/iphone7.png" alt="Image" title="iPhone 7"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></section>
```

Comment: Этот вопрос уже был вчера. Вы его удалили и пересоздали заново?

Comment: @andreymal он затерялся среди многочисленных, ответа так и не нашлось

Comment: А постоянное пересоздание одних и тех же вопросов может привести к запрету на создание вопросов. Для привлечения внимания к вопросу есть специальные инструменты вроде конкурсов

Comment: @andreymal хорошо, спасибо за информацию. Извините, вы не можете подсказать, какую я допустил ошибку с якорями?